Android SDK: setProfileId not working
SDK Version: 8.1.5
implementation 'com.salesforce.marketingcloud:marketingcloudsdk:8.1.5'
Issue: when setting the profileId the value is not synchronized with the SF backend.
Furthermore, it seems like the device is not registered on the SF console at all, we can't reach it with notifications.
        fun registerUserToSalesForce(salesForceId: String?) {

            salesForceId ?: return

            SFMCSdk.requestSdk { sdk ->
                sdk.identity.setProfileId(salesForceId)
            }
        }


Other issues we found:
        fun registerUserToSalesForce(salesForceId: String?) {

            salesForceId ?: return

            SFMCSdk.requestSdk { sdk ->
                sdk.identity.setProfileId(salesForceId)

                sdk.mp { --> the code never enters here
                    it.moduleIdentity.profileId
                }

                --> the map object returned here is not the one from the documentation at all
                https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/trouble-shooting/trouble-shooting-push-setup.html
                (sdk.getSdkState()["PUSH"] as JSONObject).let {
                    Timber.d("this")
                }
            }
        }



If your code is never getting to the sdk.mp { } code then the Marketing Cloud SDK did not successfully complete initialization. Turn on logging and look at logcat. The SDK is very good at telling you what you've done wrong. If that fails, open a support case -- but know that the first thing you're going to be asked for is logs so you might as well give it a go ;)

So it turned out that when initialising the SDK I had a duplicated line of code, something like
SFMCSdkModuleConfig.build {    SFMCSdkModuleConfig.build {                pushModuleConfig = MarketingCloudConfig.builder().apply { [...]        }     } }
Notice the double SFMCSdkModuleConfig.build.
The SDK wouldn't log any error nor the compiler would, but then it wouldn't work at runtime.
My bad for the mistake, but I'd expect at least some compiling error.
Thanks for your help @BillMote

Interesting. I would have never guessed that as a potential problem. The logging should have noted somewhere that the module was not successfully initialized in time. Now I've gotta go try this. hahaha

I was able to get this  D  ~~ SFMCSdk v1.0.4 Initialization Started ~~  D  Initializing 0 modules.  D  Module init latch time exceeded: false  D  SFMC SDK Ready took 1ms.  D  ~~ SFMCSdk Initialization Complete ~~
With the key being Initializing 0 modules, but yeah, that's not going to be an obvious issue to a customer. I'll present this to the team and maybe we'll beef up the logging around that.

Yeah I noticed that but I thought that was just the standard log for the initialised SDK :-)
Thanks!
